# Referenciar a própria classe na herança de forma dinâmica

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Bom dia,

eu tenho o seguinte código em c# asp.net-Core:

```
public class AgentsTrans : BaseTrans<AgentsTrans>
```

BaseTrans é uma classe base genérica que espera receber uma classe como parâmetro (AgentsTrans).

Neste caso, está funcionando, porém como há muitos arquivos e eu teria que modificar todos um por um, gostaria de saber se não conhecem um meio de passar esse parâmetro de forma genérica, fazendo com que o base trans enxergasse a classe que está herdando sem eu ter que referenciá-la diretamente (como um this).

se alguém tiver uma dica, será de grande ajuda.

Caso esteja confuso ou não entendam, eu tentarei esclarecer melhor :)

Comment: Apresente as duas classes, não entendi porque  AgentsTrans  precisa herdar BaseTrans sendo que essa depende de AgentsTrans...

Answer (score -1):

Olá. a pergunta ficou confusa mais acredito que entendi o que precisa.

O ideal seria você usar interfaces, ficaria assim:

```
  public interface IBaseTransRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
    {
        Task Adicionar(TEntity entity);
        Task<TEntity> ObterPorId(Guid id);
        Task<TEntity> ObterPorId(int id);
        Task<List<TEntity>> ObterTodos();
        Task Atualizar(TEntity entity);
        Task Remover(Guid id);
        Task Remover(int id);
        Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Buscar(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
        Task<int> SaveChanges();
    }


    public interface IAgentsTransRepository : IBaseTransRepository<AgentsTrans>
    {
        Task<AgentsTrans> ObterTodosOsAgentes(int IdUsuario);

    }
```